# Operator "new" in JavaScript according to class I want to use in few JavaScript files

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, new-operator

I have a few JavaScript files with some jQuery code. I am including this files to the my JavaServerPages files according to needs. I am wondering how can I create object, class or something common in JavaScript, which I can use in another JavaScript files?

I have created something similar to this:

```
function Util() {

    Util.getString = function() {
        var newString = "hello";
        return newString;
    }
}
```

It takes place in my basic JavaScript file. I have included it on my basic layout JSP file. I am using it in a jQuery function in another JavaScript file in this way:

```
var util = new Util(); 
Util.getString();
```

It works properly. But why can I not use `util.getString()`? `util` is my just created object, wright?
What is the best solution to my issue?

Comment: You're confusing JavaScript with a language that supports classes. You want to look at prototype inheritance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work

Comment: That one you created is a static method. When creating the objects with `new` they share this same prototype, think of it as a kind of inheritance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `prototype` of the function, [check here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new).

```
function Util() {
}

Util.prototype.getString = function() {
    var newString = "hello";
    return newString;
};

var util = new Util(); 
util.getString();
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want a single static object in the global namespace on the page...

```
var util = new function(){
  this.getString = function(){
    ...
  }
}
```

or

```
var util = {
  getString : function(){
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your function without `new()`

```
var Util = {

    getString : function(){
    }

};
```

That way, `getString()` is already contained in an object. So you don't need to instantiate a class(function acts class in JavaScript) with `new()`.